# Copy rows of data from one workbook to another based on a value being met in 1 column - syntax error

Tags: excel, vba

I need a row of data after column A to be copied from 1 workbook (quotes) (sheet name is Quote Database) to another workbook (Confirmed Orders) (sheet name is Orders Confirmed) if an x has been marked in column A on quotes workbook. I would also need column G of the cells with the x in to be highlighted a particular colour on the quotes workbook & then the x's to be removed after the data has been copied.

I hope this makes sense. I have looked at a couple of codes online but none seem to match exactly what I need.

This is my current one

```
Sub ConfirmedDatabaseAdd()

    Const WB_PATH As String = "S:\Dott Work\Good Order 2024\Quotes\Confirmed Orders.xlsx"
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, shtDest As Worksheet, i As Long

    
    Set srcSht = ActiveSheet
    


    For i = 2 To srcSht.Range("A" & srcSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If srcSht.Cells(i, 1) = "x" Then
            If shtDest Is Nothing Then
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=WB_PATH)
                Set shtDest = wb.Sheets("Orders Confirmed")
        
   End If
            srcSht.Cells(i, 1).Copy _
           srcSheeet.Cells(i, 2).Resize(, srcSheet.Columns.Count - 1).Copy _
     


    
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then wb.Close True
    
    MsgBox "Your quotes have been copied to the Confirmed Orders database"
    
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I've managed to sort this myself.